# Solving for combinations and/or multiples of numbers that have a specific sum

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, education, word-problem

[A mathematics workbook](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=87617668988783940499) for elementary school children (4th grade in the United States) poses [the following word problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6PTs.jpg) and asks the reader to pick from 20 different toys, each with a specific price, and find combination(s) that would allow a person to spend *all* of the money they have ($43.94).

I am wondering if there is a straightforward way for these young students without a background in combinatorics and/or linear algebra to go about solving this problem. A trial-and-error approach may be the only viable option for them, but it seems like a rather daunting task.

Comment: Do they have a background in computer programming? :-)

Comment: @joriki Haha - no, not at this stage in their lives.

Comment: I call bogus on this being from a mathematics workbook for 4th graders. I've heard tons of similar claims over the years, and they were all made up - though in one case, a rather foolish high school teacher decided to offer "gang-banger math test" that had been circulating on the internet to his students, who were not amused. He lost his job over it (I had seen the "test" myself before he did it). I'm guessing that the author of this question chose the numbers so that it is impossible.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Not bogus, but thanks for your overwhelming skepticism. PDF of packet now linked for download above.

Comment: I suppose it does offer practice in adding decimals, and in some general problem-solving techniques. But this is not a problem amenable to "Expressions and equations" as the supplementary material indicated. It pretty much has to be brute-forced, with maybe some shortcuts (such as handling the fractional and integer parts separately like I did. As a challenge problem, this is okay. But as part of a regular curriculum, I don't think much of it.

Answer (score 1):

My guess was wrong. One solution is to buy two tractors, four racecars and four pinwheels:
$$2 \times 5.97 = 11.94\\4 \times (7.13 + 0.87) = 32.00\\32.00 + 11.94 = 43.94$$

Found by noting that tractors fall $3$ cents short of a full number of dollars, meaning two of them are needed to obtain the needed $94$ cents. Which left $\$32$. Then noticing that a racecar and pinwheel together are $\$8$.

I am doubtful it is the only solution.

Comment: Absolutely not the only way. Use the amount for $3$ race cars & $3$ pinwheels to buy $2$ bears & $2$ xylophones ($2 \times (4.89 + 7.11) = 24$) would also work.

Comment: Thank you both for these examples. Indeed there appear to be many solutions, but finding an exact number of combinations seems outside the scope of an elementary classroom.